# How to add Click Event in CircleImageView Xamarin

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android

Hey everyone how do i add click event in refractored.controls.CircleImageView 
I set in axml the

```
           android:clickable="true"
```

my Code

```
       NavigationView navigationView = FindViewById<NavigationView>(Resource.Id.nav_view);
        if (navigationView != null)
        {
            SetUpDrawerContent(navigationView);
            var navEvnt = navigationView.FindViewById<CircleImageView>(Resource.Id.masterUser);
            navEvnt.Click += (sender, e) => 
            {
                Intent inf = new Intent(navigationView.Context, typeof(MessageLayout));
                StartActivity(inf); 
            };
        }
```

but Im always getting an error of System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object. sounds like couldnt find my CircleImageView id

Comment: Can you show more of your XML? I need to see the <CircleImageView>-Tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image: headerLayout]
I forgot that my CircleImageView is in my nav_header layout so get it done i must first get headerlayout using the image above.